# "Error constructing proxy" on gnome terminal

Tags: debian, gnome, virtualbox, gnome-terminal

I just installed a fresh copy of Debian 8.4 in VirtualBox 5.0.20.

I am now attempting to install the "Guest Additions" CD. To do so I had to change my fstab so I am able to execute things from the CD, so this is already fixed.

But now I get the following error:

```
root@debian:/media/cdrom# ./autorun.sh
Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: The connection is closed
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the permissions in `fstab` back to the default.  As a normal user:
2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install build-essential module-assistant`
3. `sudo m-a prepare`
4. Mount the Guest Additions CD using the VirtualBox Menu (`sudo mount /media/cdrom`)
5. `sudo sh /media/cdrom/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`

If the error you noted still occurs, make sure your Virtual Network Adapter is Enabled, like so:
[image: VirtualBox Settings -Network]

Comment: I had a slightly different error trying to execute autorun.sh . I had installed gnome-session before, following a different post. After instead executing `sudo bash VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`, it installed fine for me. No idea if installing gnome-session was needed after all